# How can an IP header length be variable?

Tags: tcp, header, ip, router

I'm reading on this topic, and I just found that IP headers, or even TCP headers, can be of variable length.

I thought routers will use a known length, divided into segments of a known format, to do whatever they do. So, how can you know which segements of bits mean what, if the length of the header is variable?

Comment: This is probably better asked at [networkengineering.se]. But in short: Please see the relevant parts in the Wikipedia articles, i.e. [IPv4 header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol_version_4#Header), [IPv6 header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_packet#Fixed_header) and [TCP header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure). For IPv4 and TCP the "Options" part is the variable part, IPv6 has for this the concept of extension headers.

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand it, is that the Options field at the end of the header determines the total length of the header (present if the Length field value > 5). The Length field has a minimum value of 5 (no options present) and a maximum of 15. This indicates a header length from 20 bytes (5 × 32 bits) to 60 bytes (15 × 32 bits). As all other fields apart from the Options field have a fixed length, it is clear where the header ends and where a given field is supposed to be. The Option field in itself also includes a Option length field for determining the length of Option data.

Comment: Does this mean the first 20 bytes are necessary for the IP header? That makes more sense now to me. I thought variable length meant you can use whatever you want & discard whatever you want. Cheers!

Comment: Yes, at least 20 bytes are always used (: